# CSS Style Tag Identifier not working - Glowing Text Effect

Tags: html, css

This is the button structure.

```
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="873" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">RESERVE NOW</button>
```

In the browser **developer tool**, if I click on **New Style Rule**, this is the new css rule created:

```
button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt {
}
```

The problem is that, the other CSS rules does not accept this Identifier Tag as I'm using it... It's giving an error message in the Visual Studio Code and, nothing happens in the browser. The glowing text effect it is not working.

The tooltip Alert says for every concatenation point in the rule **{ Expected css (ccs-lcurlyexpected)**

@-webkit-keyframes button (.) single_add_to_cart_button (.) button (.) alt {

@-moz-keyframes  button (.) single_add_to_cart_button (.) button (.) alt {

@keyframes  button (.) single_add_to_cart_button (.) button (.) alt {

**This is the whole code in the CSS file:** What I doing wrong please? Any help I really appreciate!! Thank you in advance.

```
button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt {
  color: #fff;
  animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #e60073, 0 0 40px #e60073, 0 0 50px #e60073, 0 0 60px #e60073, 0 0 70px #e60073;
  }

  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #ff4da6, 0 0 40px #ff4da6, 0 0 50px #ff4da6, 0 0 60px #ff4da6, 0 0 70px #ff4da6, 0 0 80px #ff4da6;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #e60073, 0 0 40px #e60073, 0 0 50px #e60073, 0 0 60px #e60073, 0 0 70px #e60073;
  }

  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #ff4da6, 0 0 40px #ff4da6, 0 0 50px #ff4da6, 0 0 60px #ff4da6, 0 0 70px #ff4da6, 0 0 80px #ff4da6;
  }
}

/*glow*/
@keyframes button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #e60073, 0 0 40px #e60073, 0 0 50px #e60073, 0 0 60px #e60073, 0 0 70px #e60073;
  }

  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #ff4da6, 0 0 40px #ff4da6, 0 0 50px #ff4da6, 0 0 60px #ff4da6, 0 0 70px #ff4da6, 0 0 80px #ff4da6;
  }
}
```

Comment: The name you are giving a keyframe can not be a full CSS selector like the ones you are trying to use, it needs to conform to this format: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/custom-ident

Comment: The whole thing you are building there, appears to make rather little sense. The animation name you specify here, `animation: glow ...` - the `glow` part - must match the name of a keyframe definition.

Comment: @CBroe, Thank you for the help, But I didn`t get your point in relation to the second answer. Could you show us an example please?

Comment: I changed my CSS Class to button-single_add_to_cart_button-button-alt but nothing happens

Comment: It's the name of the keyframes that you need to change. It should be glow. Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes to understand the syntax better.

Comment: [You don't need vendor prefixes for keyframes](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_keyframes) with modern browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the big help. I post here the answer, but based on the commets that all fellows have made! Thank you so much!

```
button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt {
  color: #fff;
  animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes glow {

@-moz-keyframes  glow {

@keyframes  glow {
```

Comment: Unless you are supporting Chrome Version 8 or Firefor Version 15 you don't need the prefixes.